# Scan for connected device in a wifi network iOS

Tags: ios, wifi, scanning, local-network

I want to fetch IP address & hostname for all the devices connected in a wifi network.
I am using [MMLanScan](https://github.com/mavris/MMLanScan) and i am able to retrieve IP address of all the connected devices but device name is always empty.

How to fetch the host name of the connected devices ?

Is there any other library available for this ? 
or any information related to this ?

Comment: You can discover a name by performing a DNS lookup on the inaddr-arpa domain with the reversed IPv4 address, but it is unlikely that you will find details for most home networks.  Larger enterprise networks may have configured this.

Comment: @Paulw11 :- Can you help with sample code for ios ?
I want host name of connected devices. I am able to retrieve ssid of the router.